# Using rtl in Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, right-to-left

I'm using a google sheet to send a message with google script (Gmailapp). as the email is written in persian, it should be shown from right to left; however, it's not as I expected. do you have any idea how can make it rtl?

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // First column
    var message = 'سلام '+row[0]+' عزیز،'+" \n"+row[2];
    var html= '<body>' +  '<h1 dir="rtl"> message </h1>' + '</body>'
    var alias=GmailApp.getAliases()
    var emailSent = row[4]; // Third column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'نظرسنجی';
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,message,{from: alias[0], htmlbody: html});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Where is it not shown as rtl? In Google script editor? In gmail? In web browser?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what the expected output is and what the real email looks like?